# android code to press a button automatically when it receives a certain order

Tags: android

How can I trigger a button click event through code in Android? Basically, I want to trigger the button click programmatically when some other event occurs.
thank you

Comment: Why don't you just call your method containing your business logic "when some other event occurs"?

Comment: button.perfomClick() use this when you receive a certain order to perfom click on button. @CommonsWare has a valid point.

Comment: @CommonsWare  because the button has some animations to be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need a bit more to go on than this, which button do want to emulate being pressed when the event is triggered?

For example if you want to press the back button you can just call

```
onBackPressed();
```

inside your activity, other button actions might require more complex calls.

or if you want to press one of the buttons you have created inside your layout you can call

```
button.performClick();
```

Comment: I want to thank you now after 6 years dear :)  Aedis.